# create a pagination with xajax

Tags: php, xajax

I have a problem. at the time of my query, I show more than 100 rows and I wonder if anyone can make a page to show me only 25 rows per page

Thanks

Comment: What db are you using???

Comment: sorry i don't see you... its MySQL.

Comment: There's an excellent video tutorial on how to do this here: youtube.com/phpapplied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using ready made solution.

1. If you can work with jQuery oick one of [these](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/) plugins
2. You can also use [JQuery DataTable](http://datatables.net/). Check [this](http://www.packtpub.com/article/data-tables-datatables-plugin-jquery-1.3-with-php) example
3. Or you can write a custom solution. [This](http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/php-ajax-pagination-class) might help

Comment: thanks for answered. I would check this examples. let's see what i can do. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE <conditions>
LIMIT 25 OFFSET <offset>
```

Comment: thanks for answered, nut i need some like this [http://demos.99points.info/super_paging/](http://demos.99points.info/super_paging/)